# java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run this pipeline script

```
#!groovy

@NonCPS
def findCommand(filePath) {
    def file = new File(filePath)
    def text = file.getText()
    def components = new XmlSlurper().parseText( text )

    def map = new HashMap<>()

    components.component.each { def component->
        map << ["${component.@application}" : [:]]
        def componentMap = map.get("${component.@application}")
        component.environments.environment.each { def environment->
            componentMap << ["${environment.@name}" : [:]]
            def actionMap = componentMap.get("${environment.@name}")
            environment.actions.action.each { def action->
                actionMap << ["${action.@toDo}" : action]
            }
        }
    }

    components = null
    text = null
    file = null

    return map
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
                echo "Running ${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
                echo "Parameters: ${params.environment} ${params.actions} ${params.applications}"

                script{
                    try {
                         map = findCommand("XXX.xml")
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        echo "Catching the NonCPS Exception";
                    }
                    echo "${map}"
                }

                build job: "sample echo", parameters:   [ 
                                                            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'application', value: "${params.application}"], 
                                                            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'environment', value: "${params.environment}"]
                                                        ]
            }
         }
     }
     post {
         failure {
             echo "Build failed..."
         }
     }

}
```

I know I'm using XmlSlurper, but I've also specified the code-block to be @NonCPS. However, this is still throwing a java.IO.NonSerializableException.

I also tried using a try-catch block to catch the exception, but that didn't seem to work either. 
I'd gladly appreciate some help in how I could make the build completely cleanly. Thanks :(

Answer (score 2):

The answer was in the exception. It's quite weird, but changing

```
components.component.each { def component->
        map << ["${component.@application}" : [:]]
        def componentMap = map.get("${component.@application}")
        component.environments.environment.each { def environment->
            componentMap << ["${environment.@name}" : [:]]
            def actionMap = componentMap.get("${environment.@name}")
            environment.actions.action.each { def action->
                actionMap << ["${action.@toDo}" : action]
            }
        }
    }
```

to

```
components.component.each { def component->
        def application = "${component.@application}".toString()
        map << [ (application) : [:]]
        def componentMap = map.get(application)
        component.environments.environment.each { def environment->
            def name = "${environment.@name}".toString()
            componentMap << [ (name) : [:]]
            def actionMap = componentMap.get(name)
            environment.actions.action.each { def action->
                def toDo = "${action.@toDo}".toString()
                def actionString = action.toString()
                actionMap << [ (toDo) : (actionString)]
            }
        }
    }
```

solved the issue. It had to do with the (non serializable) XMLSlurper data structure type still being carried into my HashMap.

Comment: thank you. this helped me. I was adding items of type parser.parseText(xml) to a list and experienced something similar. Now, I'm doing a toString() and it's working fine

Comment: See also [Error: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881133/error-java-io-notserializableexception-groovy-util-slurpersupport-attributes).