# Error: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using @NonCPS in my Jenkinsfile function Because I need to get attributes on XML use  XmlSlurper and i'm still getting java.io.NotSerializableException error even with the @NonCPS annotation.

Follow is my code

```
    @Field prBranchCoverage
    @NonCPS
def xmlCovergeParse(CoverageXml) {
    println "start coverage"
    def prParser = new XmlSlurper()
    prParser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", false) 
    prParser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    def prCovergeDoc = prParser.parseText(CoverageXml)
    def branchCoverage = prCovergeDoc['@line-rate']
    return branchCoverages
}
stage('Pr coverage ') {
                sh "mvn -V -B -U cobertura:cobertura -PcodehausCoverage -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DskipWeaving=true test"
        publishTestResults cobertura: [archive: true,pattern: "**/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml"]
        def CoverageXml = readFile file: './target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml'
        def prBranchCoverage = xmlCovergeParse(CoverageXml)
        echo "start coverage"

        println prBranchCoverage

            }
```

I get error is:

```
Error: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@72e69aed
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@1a22d024
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
```

Could anyone help this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your method `xmlCovergeParse(CoverageXml)` returns non serializable object

jenkins requires all variables in the pipeline to be [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) because the next step could be executed on other node then the previous one. so to transfer variables between the nodes they will be serialized.

just add `return branchCoverages.toString()` in your method `xmlCovergeParse`